# Create an elliptic curved border

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to have an elliptic curved border on an HTML element?
It should look like this:

[image: example]

The grey area is my general header, the black area my content on each view.
It get's set up like this:

my `_Layout.cshtml` looks like this:

```
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

The essential Part is the `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, which is the grey area.
Now I want this element to look like in my picture.

Please let me know, if you require further information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking for something like this: ?

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e36uD/1/

*Markup*:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- your data-role="page" -->
    <div class="top"></div> <!-- your data-role="header" -->
    <div class="content"></div> <!-- your data-role="content" -->
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.container {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.top {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0 45% 45%;
}
```

As with other *** [shorthands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) ***, `border-radius` too is: `top right bottom left;`

Comment: I was especially looking for the line `border-radius: 0 0 45% 45%`, thank you!